# Android ScrollView not filling full width of screen after rotating

Tags: android, scrollview, screen-orientation, android-scrollview, screen-rotation

My app is working fine and there is just one issue: When the screen is held horizontally, the ScrollView does not fill the parent.
The part of the xml is:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/hsvShowDay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff00ff00"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/svShowDay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffff0000"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tlShowDay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isScrollContainer="true" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/trEmptyRow" >                    
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I have already tried setting

```
android:fillViewport=true
```

as well as resetting the layout parameters in the onCreate method like so:

```
ScrollView svCalendar = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.svShowDay);
ScrollView.LayoutParams params = new ScrollView.LayoutParams(ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
svCalendar.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Can anyone tell me, what I am doing wrong? Is there anything I need to change? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today morning I tried adding `android:fillViewport="true"` to the ScrollView again. It still didn't work, but as both answers suggested that I add it, I tried adding it to the HorizontalScrollView and with that my app finally gets the functionality that I expected.

So in short the answer is to add `android:fillViewport="true"` to the HorizontalScrollView.

PS: When I also add `android:fillViewport="true"` to the ScrollView, then the TableLayout gets centered in the middle of my ScrollView. (This is not needed for my app, but it could help out someone else one day.)

Thanks for the two answers that pushed me in the right direction!

Comment: I have been trying to do this for the past 2 days but somehow it used to not work on tablets and phone, when I used a HorizontalScrollView, the first element used to get cropped on a phone but it was fine on a tablet, adding android:fillViewport="true" solved my issue, thankyou so much for that.

Comment: Adding ScrollView.LayoutParams params = new ScrollView.LayoutParams(ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
svCalendar.setLayoutParams(params); to bottom of Oncreate fixed issue for me

Answer (score 2):

Try to add another layout between HorizontalScrollView and ScrollView.

Offtop:

1. And use match_parent instead fill_parent
2. Add "android:fillViewport=true" for all ScrollView's anyway

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. Unfortunately, adding another layout didn't solve my issue. And I use fill_parent for compatibility reasons. (The "match_parent" in table layout was due to a test if changing it would lead to a different result.) `android:fillViewport` finally solved my issue, but I had to add it to HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: Nice! For future: add "fillViewport=true" anyway for all ScrollViews ))

Comment: Well, I'd usually agree, but in my case adding fillViewport="true" to the ScrollView actually messes up the design. But I will definitely add it every time, when something does not fit the whole screen as I'd expect it to!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot

> android:fillViewport="true" for your scroll view

**Side note**

Having two nested scroll view containers is a bad idea. And might be the reason for scroll/resizing problems.

I am not sure what is the purpose of scroll view into a horizontal scroll view, but if you want to achieve horizontal and vertical scroll view, better use either `GridView` or `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I was indeed missing `android:fillViewport="true"`, but I had to add it to the HorizontalScrollView. Could you elaborate why two nested scroll view containers are a bad idea? This nesting is the only solution that I found which allows me to either scroll down or to the side without doing both at the same time. And how can GridView or RecyclerView be used to achieve scrolling in both directions? (When I googled it, I only found some propositions which used a similar trick to mine.) Thanks in advance for helping me understand android better.